# How to parse a CSV file in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I'm working on a long Bash script.  I want to read cells from a CSV file into Bash variables.  I can parse lines and the first column, but not any other column.  Here's my code so far:

```
  cat myfile.csv|while read line
  do
    read -d, col1 col2 < <(echo $line)
    echo "I got:$col1|$col2"
  done
```

It's only printing the first column.  As an additional test, I tried the following:

`read -d, x y < <(echo a,b,)`

And $y is empty.  So I tried:

`read x y < <(echo a b)`

And $y is `b`.  Why?

Comment: have you considered `awk` to use `$1`, `$2`, etc?

Comment: as a sidenote: command < <(echo "string") ---> command <<< "string"

Comment: The 'cut' command line program was designed for that: http://ss64.com/bash/cut.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287982/bash-parse-csv-with-quotes-commas-and-newlines

Comment: You want to lose the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: I’ll suggest awk if that helps

Comment: See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You need to use `IFS` instead of `-d`:

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
do
    echo "I got:$col1|$col2"
done < myfile.csv
```

To skip a given number of header lines:

```bash
skip_headers=3
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
do
    if ((skip_headers))
    then
        ((skip_headers--))
    else
        echo "I got:$col1|$col2"
    fi
done < myfile.csv
```

Note that for general purpose CSV parsing you should use a specialized tool which can handle quoted fields with internal commas, among other issues that Bash can't handle by itself. Examples of such tools are [`cvstool`](http://colin.maudry.com/csvtool-manual-page/) and [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: The proposed solution is fine for very simple CSV files, that is, if the headers and values are free of commas and embedded quotation marks.  It is actually quite tricky to write a generic CSV parser (especially since there are several CSV "standards").  One approach to making CSV files more amenable to *nix tools is to convert them to TSV (tab-separated values), e.g. using Excel.

Comment: It is interesting that I cannot do mkdir in the body. I'm getting `command not found`. Only the `echo` works.

Comment: @Zsolt: There's no reason that should be the case. You must have a typo or a stray non-printing character.

Comment: I figured it out. I called one of the variables PATH. Rookie mistake

Comment: @Zsolt I recommend always using lowercase or mixed case variable names for that very reason.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You should enclose the seperator e.g. when using `;`: `while IFS=";" read col1 col2; do ...`

Comment: @thomas.mc.work: That's true in the case of semicolons and other characters that are special to the shell. In the case of a comma, it's not necessary and I tend to prefer to omit characters that are unnecessary. For example, you could always specify variables for expansion using curly braces (e.g. `${var}`), but I omit them when they're not necessary. To me, it looks cleaner.

Comment: I extended the case for the long row here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40331348/54964

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, From some time, bash source tree offer a loadable builtin csv parser! Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)! Of course there are some limitations...

Comment: Is there any option to skip header?

Comment: @AlwinJose: I edited my answer to show a way to do that.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Can you please explain what does the line `done < myfile.csv` do?

Comment: @MehdiCharife: It redirects the contents of the file into the `while` loop (where the fields are split and processed). It's equivalent to something like `cat myfile.csv | while` but it doesn't set up a subshell and so variables set within the loop retain their values when the loop is finished. See [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more information.

Answer (score 20):

> ## How to parse a CSV file in Bash?

Coming late to this question and as [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) do offer new features, because this question stand about [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and because none of already posted answer show this powerful and compliant way of doing **precisely this**.

### Parsing CSV files under *`bash`*, using *loadable module*

**Conforming to [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)**, a string like this sample *CSV row*:

> ```
> 12,22.45,"Hello, ""man"".","A, b.",42
> ```

should be splitted as

> ```
> 1  12
> 2  22.45
> 3  Hello, "man".
> 4  A, b.
> 5  42
> ```

### bash *loadable* .C compiled modules.

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could create, edit, and use ***loadable [c](/questions/tagged/c) compiled modules***. Once loaded, they work like any other ***builtin***!! ( You may find more information at [source tree](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/examples/loadables/README). ;)

Current source tree (Oct 15 2021, bash V5.1-rc3) do contain a bunch of samples:

```
accept        listen for and accept a remote network connection on a given port
asort         Sort arrays in-place
basename      Return non-directory portion of pathname.
cat           cat(1) replacement with no options - the way cat was intended.
csv           process one line of csv data and populate an indexed array.
dirname       Return directory portion of pathname.
fdflags       Change the flag associated with one of bash's open file descriptors.
finfo         Print file info.
head          Copy first part of files.
hello         Obligatory "Hello World" / sample loadable.
...
tee           Duplicate standard input.
template      Example template for loadable builtin.
truefalse     True and false builtins.
tty           Return terminal name.
uname         Print system information.
unlink        Remove a directory entry.
whoami        Print out username of current user.
```

There is an full working *`cvs`* parser ready to use in `examples/loadables` directory: **[csv.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/examples/loadables/csv.c)**!!

Under [Debian GNU/Linux](https://debian.org/) based system, you may have to install [bash-builtins](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/bash-builtins) package by

```
apt install bash-builtins
```

### Using *loadable bash-builtins*:

Then:

```
enable -f /usr/lib/bash/csv csv
```

From there, you could use `csv` as a ***bash builtin***.

With my sample: `12,22.45,"Hello, ""man"".","A, b.",42`

```
csv -a myArray '12,22.45,"Hello, ""man"".","A, b.",42'
printf "%s\n" "${myArray[@]}" | cat -n
     1      12
     2      22.45
     3      Hello, "man".
     4      A, b.
     5      42
```

Then in a loop, processing a file.

```
while IFS= read -r line;do
    csv -a aVar "$line"
    printf "First two columns are: [ '%s' - '%s' ]\n" "${aVar[0]}" "${aVar[1]}"
done <myfile.csv
```

This way is clearly the quickest and strongest than using any other combination of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) builtins or fork to any binary.

Unfortunely, depending on your system implementation, if your version of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) was compiled *without `loadable`*, this may not work...

### Complete sample with multiline CSV fields.

**Conforming to [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)**, a string like this **single** *CSV row*:

> ```
> 12,22.45,"Hello ""man"",
> This is a good day, today!","A, b.",42
> ```

should be splitted as

> ```
> 1  12
> 2  22.45
> 3  Hello "man",
>    This is a good day, today!
> 4  A, b.
> 5  42
> ```

#### Full sample script for parsing CSV containing multilines fields

Here is a small sample file with **1** headline, **4** columns and **3** rows. Because two fields do contain ***newline***, the file are **6** lines length.

```
Id,Name,Desc,Value
1234,Cpt1023,"Energy counter",34213
2343,Sns2123,"Temperatur sensor
to trigg for alarm",48.4
42,Eye1412,"Solar sensor ""Day /
Night""",12199.21
```

And a small script able to parse this file correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

enable -f /usr/lib/bash/csv csv

file="sample.csv"
exec {FD}<"$file"

read -ru $FD line
csv -a headline "$line"
printf -v fieldfmt '%-8s: "%%q"\\n' "${headline[@]}"
numcols=${#headline[@]}

while read -ru $FD line;do
    while csv -a row "$line" ; (( ${#row[@]} < numcols )) ;do
        read -ru $FD sline || break
        line+=$'\n'"$sline"
    done
    printf "$fieldfmt\\n" "${row[@]}"
done
```

This may render: (I've used `printf "%q"` to represent non-printables characters like *newlines* as `$'\n'`)

```
Id      : "1234"
Name    : "Cpt1023"
Desc    : "Energy\ counter"
Value   : "34213"

Id      : "2343"
Name    : "Sns2123"
Desc    : "$'Temperatur sensor\nto trigg for alarm'"
Value   : "48.4"

Id      : "42"
Name    : "Eye1412"
Desc    : "$'Solar sensor "Day /\nNight"'"
Value   : "12199.21"
```

You could find a full working sample there: [csvsample.sh.txt](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/csvsample.sh.txt) or
[csvsample.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/csvsample.sh).

### Note:

In this sample, I use *head line* to determine *row width* (number of columns). If you're *head line* could hold *newlines*, (or if your CSV use more than 1 head line). You will have to pass number or columns as argument to your script (and the number of head lines).

### Warning:

Of course, parsing CSV using this is not perfect! This work for many simple CSV files, but care about encoding and security!! For sample, this module won't be able to handle binary fields!

Read carefully [csv.c source code comments](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/examples/loadables/csv.c) and [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)!

### Note about quoted multi-line fields

In particular if multi-line field is located on last column, this method won't loop correctly upto second quote.

For this, you have to check quotes parity in `$line` before parsing using `csv` module.

Comment: Of course, parsing csv under [tag:bash] is not perfect: `csv` *loadable* won't be able to  handle binary fields and you may encounter *encoding* issues and/or **security** issues... Read carefully  [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)!!!

Answer (score 11):

From the `man` page:

> -d delim
>           The first character of delim is used to terminate the input line,
>   rather than newline.

You are using `-d,` which will terminate the input line on the comma. It will not read the rest of the line. That's why $y is empty.

Answer (score 7):

We can parse csv files with quoted strings and delimited by say | with following code

```
while read -r line
do
    field1=$(echo "$line" | awk -F'|' '{printf "%s", $1}' | tr -d '"')
    field2=$(echo "$line" | awk -F'|' '{printf "%s", $2}' | tr -d '"')

    echo "$field1 $field2"
done < "$csvFile"
```

`awk` parses the string fields to variables and `tr` removes the quote.

Slightly slower as `awk` is executed for each field.

Comment: Good, you can also use coma (,)

Comment: Processing a line at a time with Awk is a gross antipattern. `awk -F'|' '{ gsub(/"/, ""); print $1, $2 }' "$csvFile"`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer from @Dennis Williamson, it may be helpful to skip the first line when it contains the header of the CSV:

```sh
{
  read
  while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
  do
    echo "I got:$col1|$col2"
  done 
} < myfile.csv
```

Comment: instead of just `read` (that will uselessly populate `$REPLY` variable), you could use `_` as *garbage variable*: `read _`. Or even, you could store first lines as `header` which could be useful further in the script `IFS=, read -ra headline`. ( Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658) ;)

Comment: And maybe could you be interested by [this other post about parsing output of commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41236640/1765658) (Have a look how I parse `df -k` output).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read CSV file with some lines, so this the solution.

```
while IFS=, read -ra line
do 
    test $i -eq 1 && ((i=i+1)) && continue
    for col_val in ${line[@]}
    do
        echo -n "$col_val|"                 
    done
    echo        
done < "$csvFile"
```