# unix - count of columns in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Given a file with data like this (i.e. stores.dat file)

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
2|1|-28.03720000|153.42921670
9|2|-33.85090000|151.03274200
```

What would be a command to output the number of column names?

i.e. In the example above it would be 4. (number of pipe characters + 1 in the first line)

I was thinking something like:

```
awk '{ FS = "|" } ; { print NF}' stores.dat
```

but it returns all lines instead of just the first and for the first line it returns 1 instead of 4

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' '{print NF; exit}' stores.dat
```

Just quit right after the first line.

Comment: or `awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print NF}' stores.dat`

Comment: @JaypalSingh: that will read the whole file - no need for that, better stop early.

Comment: They both seem to return the same correct ouput, is there any performance benefit of 1 over the other (or some other benefit)?

Comment: @toop: yes, see my previous comment. My version will only read one block from the file, Jaypal's will read the whole file.

Comment: @Mat You are spot on! @loop Mat is absolutely correct. `exit` is the right way to go about it. No need to read the whole file if you only wish to know the number of columns. +1 :)

Comment: It might not matter if your file is 10 lines long. But mine is about 1 million. Definitely going with Mat's answer.

Answer (score 42):

This is a workaround (for me: I don't use awk very often):

Display the first row of the file containing the data, replace all pipes with newlines and then count the lines:

```
$ head -1 stores.dat | tr '|' '\n' | wc -l
```

Comment: For files with maaany columns (think SNP data) this is the way to go. Mat's solution returned "awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767."

Answer (score 15):

Unless you're using spaces in there, you should be able to use `| wc -w` on the first line.

`wc` is "Word Count", which simply counts the words in the input file. If you send only one line, it'll tell you the amount of columns.

Comment: I tried: head -1 stores.dat | wc -w     But that does not return what I am after

Comment: That's because you're not replacing the `|` with a space - `wc` will count words, which have to be space-separated. Use `head -1 stores.dat | tr '|' ' ' | wc -w`

Comment: Please add your comment to the answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 7):

You could try

> cat FILE | awk '{print NF}'

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution similar to Mat's awk solution:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane 'print $#F+1; exit' stores.dat
```

I've tested this on a file with 1000000 columns.

---

If the field separator is whitespace (one or more spaces or tabs) instead of a pipe:

```
perl -lane 'print $#F+1; exit' stores.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have python installed you could try:

```
python -c 'import sys;f=open(sys.argv[1]);print len(f.readline().split("|"))' \
    stores.dat
```

Comment: in this particular case, it's shorter to read from standard input `cat x.txt | python -c "print raw_input().count('|') + 1"`

Comment: shorter yes, but not faster, if there are many long files! I assumed he wanted a faster solution in the eye of pure (means surely big) data files.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually what I use for counting the number of fields:

```
head -n 1 file.name | awk -F'|' '{print NF; exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

select any row in the file (in the example below, it's the 2nd row) and count the number of columns, where the delimiter is a space:

```
sed -n 2p text_file.dat | tr ' ' '\n' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

## Proper pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way

#### Simply counting columns in file

Under bash, you could simply:

```
IFS=\| read -ra headline <stores.dat
echo ${#headline[@]}
4
```

A lot quicker as *without forks*, and reusable as `$headline` hold the full head line. You could, for sample:

```
printf " - %s\n" "${headline[@]}"
 - sid
 - storeNo
 - latitude
 - longitude
```

**Nota** This syntax will drive correctly spaces and others characters in column names.

#### Alternative: strong binary checking for max columns on each rows

What if some row do contain some extra columns?

This command will search for bigger line, counting *separators*:

```
tr -dc $'\n|' <stores.dat |wc -L
3
```

If there are max *`3`* separators, then there are ***`4`*** fields... Or if you consider:

> each *separator* (`|`) is prepended by a *Before* and followed by an *After*, trimed to 1 letter by word:

```
tr -dc $'\n|' <stores.dat|sed 's/./b&a/g;s/ab/a/g;s/[^ab]//g'|wc -L
4
```

#### Counting columns in a CSV file

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you may use  ***csv loadable plugins***:

```
enable -f /usr/lib/bash/csv csv
IFS= read -r line <file.csv
csv -a fields <<<"$line"
echo ${#fields[@]}
4
```

For more infos, see [How to parse a CSV file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Cat Kerr response.
This command is working on solaris

```
awk '{print NF; exit}' stores.dat
```

Comment: And then you're at the accepted answer minus the proper field separator. This would return "1" for the example input.

Comment: This is essentially the same as accepted answer without field separator, as Bejamin says returns 1 but should work for space delimited files.

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
head -1 stores.dat | grep -o \|  | wc -l
```