# I am trying to write S3 Bash script to be able to pass Bucket Name and Objects in them to be able to download locally

Tags: bash, loops, amazon-s3

Using this format I need to write a bash script where I can pass Bucketname and FilesNames as text files and it would run it as BucketName1/File1,File2..  FileN
                       BucketName1/File1,File2.... FileN

Below is what I have written. But I am not getting the required Output.

```
#!/bin/bash
BucketName=$1
FileName=$2
while IFS= read -r FileName
do
aws s3 cp s3://${BucketName}/${FileName} .
done
```

Comment: Hint: `echo` is your friend. Use it to help debug the script by printing out the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second argument points to the file with list of files to download, then the following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
BucketName=$1
FileName=$2
while IFS= read -r file;
#while IFS= read -r FileName
do
aws s3 cp s3://$BucketName/$file .
done < $FileName
```

Where the second argument is a file like:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

Output:

```
$ bash s3bash.sh mybucket s3files.txt
download: s3://mybucket/file1.csv to ./file1.csv         
download: s3://mybucket/file2.csv to ./file2.csv         
download: s3://mybucket/file3.csv to ./file3.csv
```

If you are passing the list of files as a delimited string, instead of the file  - check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27703327/5535604