# Reading a specific column in a CSV file with bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, csv, scp

I'm really inexperienced with bash/shell scripts. I have a large volume of files that I need to SCP across servers. I have a list of the files I need to move in a CSV file with three columns. The second column is called file_name, and contains the path of the file.

I need to read every single line of the file, but only process the second column. I found something like this on the internet:

```
#!/bin/bash

csv_file=$1

while IFS=',' read -r file_name; do
    echo -e "File Name\t: $file_name"
done < $csv_file
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

But it just seems to output all 3 columns of the file. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, I really don't know much about bash.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote and close vote for "insufficient information provided"? Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash, extract one column of a csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602181/bash-extract-one-column-of-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a variable for each column of the file being read. The last variable will get all the remaining columns. So it should be:

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 file_name col3
```

Answer (score 2):

If the output being in another singe file is acceptable, his sounds like something well suited for `awk`, which is a program built for dealing with delimited input line by line.

For example, the below may help with your problem, if I'm understanding it correctly:

```
awk -F',' '{print "File Name:\t"$2}' inputfile > outputfile
```

The `-F','` tells awk the field separator in the file is a comma.

`print` is awk's command to print output, in this case the string "File Name:\t" followed by the second field in the file, which is denoted in awk by `$i` where i is the field number (NOT index, `$0` for awk is the entire line) you're interested in.

`awk` is a very powerful tool and this is just a very simple example of the complex processing it can do - you can read more about it's features and capabilities here: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_toc.html