# Importing relevant rows(using a selection criteria) from a large csv file in R using fread and sed/gawk/awk commands

Tags: r, csv, awk, sed

I have a large csv file( 9Gb) and would like to filter out unnecessary rows before importing the data in R. I went  through the following posts and tried to implement accordingly:

[sed/awk - return rows that match certain strings at the second column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858183/sed-awk-return-rows-that-match-certain-strings-at-the-second-column)

[Importing only every Nth row from a .csv file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891841/importing-only-every-nth-row-from-a-csv-file-in-r)

[How to read specific rows of CSV file with fread function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798930/how-to-read-specific-rows-of-csv-file-with-fread-function)

I need to select data/rows  between two  dates. The data sample looks like this:

```
   dep_date     Origin  Destination dep_time  arr_time  Transport
   2016-03-10     AAA1     DSU3      900        1334     Truck                 
   2016-03-11     RGH1     ONB3      900        1534     Truck                 
   2016-03-12     WED1     FCS3      900        1134     Truck                 
   2016-03-13     SZA1     TDC3      900        1834     Truck                  
   2016-03-14     XBN1     LSQ3      900        1734     Truck                 
   2016-03-15     EPD1     QPL3      900        1434     Truck
```

I have used the following command to read the data (based on the first post mentioned above).

```
fread("D:/Administrative/test1.csv | gawk  -F '\"*,\"*' '($1 >= 2016-03-10)&& ($1 <= 2016-03-12)'")
```

and I have got the following error message:

```
   Error in fread("D:/R/test1.csv | gawk  -F '\"*,\"*' '($1 >= 2016-03-10)&&   ($1 <= 2016-03-12)'") : 
   File not found:    C:\Users\PTEWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMJHuRL\file2fd410495ab
   In addition: Warning messages:
   1: running command 'C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (D:/R/test1.csv | gawk    -       F '"*,"*' '($1 >= 2016-03-10)&& ($1 <= 2016-03-12)') >       C:\Users\PTEWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMJHuRL\file2fd410495ab' had status 1 
   2: In shell(paste("(", input, ") > ", tt, sep = "")) :
   '(D:/R/test1.csv | gawk  -F '"*,"*' '($1 >= 2016-03-10)&& ($1 <= 2016-03-  12)') > C:\Users\PTEWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMJHuRL\file2fd410495ab'     execution failed with error code 1
```

Can anyone suggest in this regard ?

Comment: You are likely running afoul of cmd interpretation of some of the quote characters.  To avoid this put your gawk program into a file and call it with `gawk -f myprog.awk` .  Do not use the `-F` flag but specify `FS` (field separator) in your program.

Answer (score 0):

The awk:

```
$ awk -v start="2016-03-10" -v end="2016-03-12" 'NR==1 || start<=$1 && end >= $1' file
  dep_date     Origin  Destination dep_time  arr_time  Transport
   2016-03-10     AAA1     DSU3      900        1334     Truck                 
   2016-03-11     RGH1     ONB3      900        1534     Truck                 
   2016-03-12     WED1     FCS3      900        1134     Truck
```

Define start and end variables `start` and `end` with: `-v start="2016-03-12"` etc. If you want to assign them from predefined (shell) variables (for example `$1` and `$2`) use `-v start=$1` etc. Based on the sample data the default `FS` should be ok.