# Can I use grep to extract a single column of a CSV file?

Tags: shell, csv, grep

I'm trying to solve o problem I have to do as soon as possible.
I have a csv file, fields separated by ;.
I'm asked to make a shell command using grep to list only the third column, using regex. I can't use cut. It is an exercise.

My file is like this:

```
1;Evan;Bell;39;Obigod Manor;Ekjipih;TN;25008
2;Wayne;Watkins;22;Lanme Place;Cotoiwi;NC;86578
3;Danny;Vega;25;Fofci Center;Momahbih;MS;21027
4;Larry;Robinson;23;Bammek Boulevard;Gaizatoh;NE;27517
5;Myrtie;Black;20;Savon Square;Gokubpat;PA;92219
6;Nellie;Greene;23;Utebu Plaza;Rotvezri;VA;17526
7;Clyde;Reynolds;19;Lupow Ridge;Kedkuha;WI;29749
8;Calvin;Reyes;47;Paad Loop;Beejdij;KS;29247
9;Douglas;Graves;43;Gouk Square;Sekolim;NY;13226
10;Josephine;Estrada;48;Ocgig Pike;Beheho;WI;87305
11;Eugene;Matthews;26;Daew Drive;Riftemij;ME;93302
12;Stanley;Tucker;54;Cure View;Woocabu;OH;45475
13;Lina;Holloway;41;Sajric River;Furutwe;ME;62184
14;Hettie;Carlson;57;Zuheho Pike;Gokrobo;PA;89098
15;Maud;Phelps;57;Lafni Drive;Gokemu;MD;87066
16;Della;Roberson;53;Zafe Glen;Celoshuv;WV;56749
17;Cory;Roberson;56;Riltav Manor;Uwsupep;LA;07983
18;Stella;Hayes;30;Omki Square;Figjitu;GA;35813
19;Robert;Griffin;22;Kiroc Road;Wiregu;OH;39594
20;Clyde;Reynolds;19;Lupow Ridge;Kedkuha;WI;29749
21;Calvin;Reyes;47;Paad Loop;Beejdij;KS;29247
22;Douglas;Graves;43;Gouk Square;Sekolim;NY;13226
23;Josephine;Estrada;48;Ocgig Pike;Beheho;WI;87305
24;Eugene;Matthews;26;Daew Drive;Riftemij;ME;93302
```

I think I should use something like: cat < test.csv | grep 'regex'.

Thanks.

Comment: A title should not just describe what tool your question is about, but *what the question actually is*. I've tried to edit to have it do so here.

Comment: That said -- do you want to *search* all columns and only print the 3rd, or search only the 3rd and print the whole line, or search the 3rd and only print the 3rd? Right now this question is very unclear.

Comment: Also, is the use of `grep` part of an assignment you were given? Why `grep` specifically, instead of a tool that *understands* the idea of columnar data natively?

Comment: Right, the question is not clear, I need to print only the third column, using grep, avoiding duplicates. It is an exercise and I'm asked to use only grep.

Comment: That's an unfortunate exercise, insofar as it's asking you to use something that's clearly the wrong tool for the job. Which version of `grep`? Are you allowed to use GNU extensions?

Comment: `cat < file | grep ...` should just be `grep ... < file`, or `grep ... file`. Don't use `cat` unless you have to -- it takes a performance penalty, *especially* when the tool you're running could otherwise parallelize when given a seekable file handle.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602181/how-to-extract-one-column-of-a-csv-file/40247280

Answer (score 16):

#### Right Tools For The Job: Using `awk` or `cut`

Assuming you want to match the third column against a specific field:

```
awk -F';' '$3 ~ /Foo/ { print $0 }' file.txt
```

...will print any line where the third field contains `Foo`. (Changing `print $0` to `print $3` would print only that third field).

If you just want to print the third column regardless, use `cut`: `cut -d';' -f3 <file.txt`

#### Wrong Tool For The Job: Using GNU `grep`

On a system where `grep` has the `-o` option, you can chain two instances together -- one to trim everything after the fourth column (and remove lines with less than four columns), another to take only the last remaining column (thus, the fourth):

```
str='foo;bar;baz;qux;meh;whatever'
grep -Eo '^[^;]*[;][^;]*[;][^;]*[;][^;]*' <<<"$str" \
  | grep -Eo '[^;]+$'
```

To explain how that works:

- `^`, outside of square brackets, matches only at the beginning of a line.
- `[^;]*` matches any character except `;` zero-or-more times.
- `[;]` matches only the character `;`.

...thus, each `[^;]*[;]` in the regex matches a single field, whether or not that field contains text. Putting four of those in the first stage means we're matching only fields, and `grep -o` tells `grep` to only emit content it was successfully able to match.

Comment: Wow, the regex is much faster than I was doing with an `if` statement with `==` comparison.

Answer (score 5):

If you just need the 3rd field and it's always properly delimited with ';'  why not use 'cut'?

```
cut -d';' -f3   <filename>
```

UPDATED:

OP wasn't clear, maybe only want to look at the 3rd line?

```
head -3 <filename> | tail -1
```

OR..   Maybe just getting of list of the things that appear in the 3rd field?

Not clear what the intended use of 'grep' would be??

```
cut -d';' -f3   <filename>  | sort -u
```

Comment: Or, if you really need to use grep `grep . input-file | cut -d';' -f3` :)

Comment: Huh? If you use `cut` it'll return only the third column, not the whole line. And if you `grep` first and *then* `cut`, as Will suggests above, then it'll search the whole line, not the 3rd column only.

Comment: ...then again, the OP isn't actually clear about what they want to do -- if they're only *searching* the 3rd column, or only *printing* the 3rd column, or restricting both the search *and* print operations.

Comment: I'm trying to print only the third column in the shell.

Comment: @DDeMartini the OP has clarified their question -- they have a homework exercise asking them to extract the third column using no tools other than `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said, using `grep` is a bad/unfortunate idea.

The only way I can think of using `grep` is to pull out a specific row where the 3rd column == some value. E.g.,

```
grep '^\([^;]*;\)\{2\}Bell;' test.txt                                                           
1;Evan;Bell;39;Obigod Manor;Ekjipih;TN;25008
```

Or if the first column is the index (not counting it as a column):

```
grep '^\([^;]*;\)\{3\}39;' test.txt  
1;Evan;Bell;39;Obigod Manor;Ekjipih;TN;25008
```

Even using `grep` in this case leads to a pretty ugly solution.

*Edit: Didn't see Charles Duffy's answer... that's pretty clever.*