# How to extract column from csv file using terminal

Tags: bash, unix, plink

I just have started using Unix system basically for running my plink analysis. I need to extract two columns (First and third) from my reference csv file and make a new csv out of it. How can i do this in unix environment?
My reference file  File.csv looks like

```
V1 V2 v3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

I want to extract column V1 and V3 and make a new csv which will be looked it. `New.csv`

```
V1 V3
1   1
2   2
```

What command line should i use to do this in unix?

Comment: I just edited the question by putting an example. If you can show me what should be command like using awk it would be of help.

Comment: Your example does not contain comma-separated values (csv).

Comment: Lets assume these are comma separated values.

Comment: `awk -F',' '{print $1 " " $3 > "New.csv"}' File.csv`

Comment: @Aryh: Plesae update your question, so that we can see how your file **really** looks like. Just mentioning in a comment, that every space in your posting is meant to be a comma, is more confusing than helpful.

Comment: @user1934428 Agree. I answered the *actual* question correctly but unfortunately didn't bring my crystal ball to guess which question I should have answered to get credit for it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602181/how-to-extract-one-column-of-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lets assume these are comma separated values. – Aryh

> I want to extract column V1 and V3 and make a new csv

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=, '{print $1,$3}' file.csv > New.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If your values are whitespace-separated, you can use `awk` to produce the desired results like so:

```
awk '{print $1 " " $3}' File.csv | column -t
```

With newer version of `column`, you can use the `-R` option to get the output columns right-aligned as per your example.

Answer (score 1):

You data is not a CSV file, because it does not contain any coma as delimiters. CSV stands for Coma Separated Values.

Your data has a column based format. For this you can use [`cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html):

```
cut -c 1-2,6-8
```

`1-2` takes "V1" and `6-8` takes a space and "V3".