# How to parse CSV file for long row in Bash?

Tags: bash, bash4

I have IDs in the first column of data.csv with headers. 
I want to skip the header and store column 1 values in the variable `ids` as `102 103 104 ...`. 
Pseudocode in the line `ids.append($col1)` where I want to append the current row value to the end of the line with a space

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/4286841/54964
while IFS=, read col1
do
    ids.append($col1) # Pseudocode
done < data.csv
```

data.csv

```
102
103
104
```

Expected output

```
ids=( 102 103 104 )
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Bash: 4.3.30(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU bash and GNU tail:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=()
while IFS=, read -r col1 coln
do
    array+=("$col1") # append $col1 to array array
done < <(tail -n +2 data.csv)

declare -p array
```

Comment: I use this here to show you content of array array.

Comment: If I replace `,` by `:` and `data.csv` by `/etc/passwd` it returns all users from my Linux system: `declare -a array='([0]="root" [1]="daemon" [2]="bin" [3]="sys" [4]="sync" [5]="games" [6]="man" [7]="lp" [8]="mail" [9]="news" [10]="uucp" [11]="proxy" [12]="www-data" [13]="backup" [14]="list" [15]="irc" [16]="gnats" [17]="nobody" [18]="libuuid" [19]="syslog" [20]="messagebus" [21]="usbmux" [22]="avahi-autoipd" [23]="avahi" [24]="kernoops" [25]="pulse" [26]="rtkit" [27]="hplip" [28]="kdm" [29]="saned" [30]="bar" [31]="sshd" [32]="cyrus" [33]="foo" [34]="dnsmasq")'`

Comment: I've updated my answer to skip first line of your file.

Comment: `col1` should contain content of first column and `coln` should contain content of  all remaining columns (here 2 and 3). I suggest to check your file for special characters: `cat -v data.csv`

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this problem. Try this: `mapfile -s 1 -t array < <(cut -d, -f 1 data.csv); declare -p array`

Comment: It works! Sorry, it was my typo in in the variable name. Output is now: `declare -a ids='([0]="100" [1]="101" [2]="102"` which seems to be correct.

Comment: Okay. `mapfile` is a bash builtin command. For more information see `help mapfile`.

Comment: Have a look! Racent [tag:bash] do offer loadable builtins wht a CSV parser! I'v posted a [demo with mulitline fileds in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)