# How can I split a folder into several folders using a csv file?

Tags: bash, csv, ubuntu, directory

I am using Ubuntu and want to split a folder of images (30k images) into different folders. However, I want to sort them (not just splitting into smaller subfolders). I have a file which contains information on the folder destination of the image. The file is structured as:

- 123.jpg, 1
- 124.jpg, 2
- 125.jpg, 3

This should be interpreted as: image 123.jpg to folder 1, image 124.jpg to folder 2, image 125.jpg to folder 3.

Is there an efficient way to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Sure, iterate over lines of the CSV files, split each line by the comma and move the file (first column) to the target directory (second column). Have you tried something like this already?

Comment: @Pavel My bad, I am new to Ubuntu and have very little experience. Could you be more specific?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Comment: Thank you! I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the files based on the description provided in the file in the following way:

`awk -F"," '{ print "mv",$1,$2}' description.txt | sh`

This assumes that the destination directories listed in `description.txt` already exist.

The `awk` reads the `description.txt` file as comma (`,`) separated (set by the `-F","`) and add the necessary strings to the 1st (`$1`) and 2nd ($2) fields. First use the above command without the `| sh` part in order to test the output. If everything is fine then add the `| sh` in order to execute them, that pipe (`|`) the output of awk into `shell`.

The `description.txt` file contains your example:

```
123.jpg, 1
124.jpg, 2
125.jpg, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file containing your files list and destinations is named **list.txt**

You can do it like this in a bash shell:

```
while IFS=, read -r file destination
do
    echo "mv $file $destination/$file"
done < list.txt
```

This is based on this question and answer:
[How to parse a CSV file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286469/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-in-bash)

Comment: You can format code by selecting it and then clicking on the button marked `{}`.

Comment: The last `$file` in your answer is unnecessary - under Linux you can more simply use the syntax `mv file directory` and it will get the original name anyway but be stored in the new directory.

Comment: Yes, you're right, just added it to offer a clearer answer