# How to get the specific data in a file and direct its output to to new file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file like this:

[image: link to the file]

I want to get the school section of the file and place it into a new file.

The output in the new file should be like this:

```
School

Texas high,SA high,Plano tech
```

Comment: also post some code, what did you try until now?

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you having problem with? Stackoverflow is a site for specific programming questions for programming enthusiasts, not a "do my job for me" service, you may want to try on some freelancing sites, where you actually offer some goods in exchange for a service.

Comment: Also, a quick SO search would give you an example where you can move from. For example, your question is kinda answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286469/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-in-bash/54361474

Comment: ytf is this an img and not a `<code>` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following awk script should solve your probelm provided you manually add the `School` heading yourself or if that remains same add it as `BEGIN { printf "School" }` in below example.

```
$ cat input_file 
Mark,Texas High, Dallas, k-5
Steve,SA high,Antonio,k-5
Adam,Plano tech,k-5

$ awk -F, 'BEGIN { sep = ""} { printf("%s%s", sep, $2); sep = ","}' < input_file 
Texas High,SA high,Plano tech
```