# Parsing a CSV file in BASH

Tags: bash, shell

I have a csv as below I needed that formatted  .

current format

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
```

Desired Output

```
a,
b,
c,
d,
e

1,
2,
3,
4,
5
```

Comment: This maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286469/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-in-bash

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Try a script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

cat ${file} | while read line
do 
  echo $line | sed 's/,/,\n/g'
  echo
done
```

Or if you don't need a blank line after each translated lines:

```sh
cat filename.csv | sed 's/,/,\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
sed "1G;s/,/,\n/g" file.csv
```

Append a new line then replace "," with ",newline"

Answer (score 0):

You tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), so a bash answer:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n\n" "${line//,/$',\n'}"
done < file.csv
```