# Trim leading whitespace from fields in csv file in Linux

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I want to trim only the leading whitespaces from a csv file that looks something like this:

```
thing1,thing2, thing something3,thing4
thing11,thing12, thing something13,thing14
etc.
```

(note: I want to keep the space between `thing` and `something3`)

so my output would be like this:

```
thing1,thing2,thing something3,thing4
thing11,thing12,thing something13,thing14
```

I've tried using `awk '{$1=$1};1' file` and a dozen other solutions that I found with a quick google search, but those usually either freeze or just do nothing in my case.

Hope someone can help me out, cheers!

Comment: Can the space also occur in the first column?

Comment: `sed 's|\s*,\s*|,|g' <input >output`

Comment: do we need to worry about trailing spaces (ie, do you need to remove trailing whitespace)?

Comment: I only needed to remove the leading spaces from the 3rd column, however thanks to @christian-fritz I got the solution and marked it as such.

Comment: See [How to parse a CSV file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/,[[:blank:]]*/,/g' file
```

Example:

```sh
> cat test.txt 
thing1,thing2, thing something3,thing4
thing12,thing12, thing something13,thing14

> cat test.txt  | sed 's/,[[:blank:]]*/,/g'
thing1,thing2,thing something3,thing4
thing12,thing12,thing something13,thing14
```

Comment: See [How to parse a CSV file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
cat file
thing1,thing2, thing something3,thing4
thing12,thing12, thing something13,thing14
```

In awk, you can deal with non-quoted csv and remove the trailing space like so:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",[[:space:]]*"; OFS=","}
{$1=$1}1' file
```

Prints:

```
thing1,thing2,thing something3,thing4
thing11,thing12,thing something13,thing14
```

Suppose you have quoted csv and you only want to change the csv delimiters -- not the embedded commas in the quoted fields, you should use a csv parser.

Given:

```
cat file
thing1,thing2, thing something3,"thing4, and 5"
thing11,thing12, thing something13,thing14
```

The **easiest** csv parser at the command line is `ruby`:

```
ruby -r CSV -e 'CSV.parse($<.read).each{|l| puts l.map(&:lstrip).to_csv}' file
```

Prints:

```
thing1,thing2,thing something3,"thing4, and 5"
thing11,thing12,thing something13,thing14
```

Answer (score 0):

Also with `awk` you can test this:

```
awk 'gsub(/, */, ",") 1' file
thing1,thing2,thing something3,thing4
thing12,thing12,thing something13,thing14
```