# Extracting file content using a for loop

Tags: bash, loops, shell, for-loop, command-line

I have following dummy table (called sif.csv):

```
1,MseI,PstI
2,AatII,PstI
3,MseI,AciI
```

Using a for loop, I would like to extract information from the table, where the nth iteration corresponds to the nth line:

I have tried the following but the script keeps failing:

```
for i in {1..$(cat sif.csv | wc -l)}; do 
sl=$(sed -n "{$i}p" sif.csv | cut -d "," -f1)
enz1=$(sed -n "{$i}p" sif.csv | cut -d "," -f2)
enz2=$(sed -n "{$i}p" sif.csv | cut -d "," -f3)
echo "$sl is $enz1 and $enz2."
done
```

I am grateful for any assistance.

Comment: try: `while IFS=, read -r sl enz1 enz2 ;do echo "$sl is $enz1 and $enz2.";done <sif.csv`

Comment: And see [How to parse a CSV file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)