# read csv output into an array and process the variable in a loop using bash

Tags: arrays, bash, csv, while-loop, process-substitution

assuming i have an output/file

```
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in
```

I want to run a while loop with `read`

```
while read r ; do 
   echo "$r";
   # extract line to $arr as array separated by ',' 
   # call some program (e.g. md5sum, echo ...) on one item of arr
done <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in   
HEREDOC
```

I would like to use `readarray` and `while`, but compelling alternatives are welcome too.

There is a specific way to have `readarray` (`mapfile`) behave correctly with process substitution, but i keep forgetting it. this is intended as a Q&A so an explanation would be nice

Comment: Regarding `I specifically want to use readarray and while` - why?

Comment: @EdMorton because i wanted to have a simple resource to go to that gave away the answer quickly to this particular problem . Anyway. I accepted your answer. The better solution is the better solution. If you have a way to "retroactive continuity"-ing my question so that it fits better with all the answers , please go for it. though maybe it is good that people can find an alternative solution to what they were searching for.

Comment: the close is unwarranted because the "duplicate" question does not come up in a search for read , array and while loop. also I was specifically asking for readarray and the special ways this behaves! it doesn't matter if there is a better way around it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `compelling alternatives are welcome too` and assuming you're just trying to populate `arr` one line at a time:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=',' read -a arr ; do
    # extract line to $arr as array separated by ','
    # echo the first item of arr
    echo "${arr[0]}"
done <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in
HEREDOC
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
1
2
3
```

or if you also need each whole input line in a separate variable `r`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r r ; do
    # extract line to $arr as array separated by ','
    # echo the first item of arr
    IFS=',' read -r -a arr <<< "$r"
    echo "${arr[0]}"
done <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in
HEREDOC
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
1
2
3
```

but bear in mind [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  great answer.  I actually tried this but my IFS was in front of while and it didn't work. moving it to the read is the trick here.

Comment: PS: i read that https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716, but it gives no alternative. Also it assumes that one only tries to convert text into another form of text (awk) ... sometimes you have some CSV-ish lists that give you input for programs to run. Programs that sadly have difficult ~plang~ bindings for a simple task (e.g. resize and rename a picture) .. that's where you quickly need the convoluted syntax below for the simplest API to do the task quickly (with little human involvement), no matter how long it will take computationally

Comment: The whole Q&A is about using a shell loop to process text, not about using a shell loop to sequence calls to other tools - that latter is why shells have loops. As for alternatives - there are too many to list, including just using grep, sed, awk, etc. depending on what it is you want to do with the input, how it's formatted, etc.

Comment: yea, maybe i could have written call <program> with first item of arr. for example `echo` .

Comment: I wouldn't chose `echo` for that as it's easily emulated in `awk`, etc., so its not a good example of when you'd need a shell loop reading text. Calling `md5sum` or similar on a part of the input line is one you can't do internally with mandatory POSIX tools so maybe that would be a good example - reading a CSV with 3 fields and outputting it with the 2nd field replaced by it's md5sum.

Answer (score 2):

If the loadable builtin `csv` is available/acceptable, something like:

```
help csv
csv: csv [-a ARRAY] string
    Read comma-separated fields from a string.
    
    Parse STRING, a line of comma-separated values, into individual fields,
    and store them into the indexed array ARRAYNAME starting at index 0.
    If ARRAYNAME is not supplied, "CSV" is the default array name.
```

---

The script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

enable csv || exit

while IFS= read -r line && csv -a arr "$line"; do
  printf '%s\n' "${arr[0]}"
done <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in
HEREDOC
```

---

- See `help enable`

---

With `bash 5.2+` there is a default path for the loadables in `config-top.h` which should be configurable at compile time.

```
BASH_LOADABLES_PATH
```

Comment: _Very_ nice; TIL. The OP's simple data doesn't call for this, but as soon as they're trying to read `4,d,"info, here"` in their input it becomes _very_ appropriate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Playing with  CSV implie to care about number of columns and potentially read more than one line for one row, if some field do contain  *newline* in it! Have a look [How I parse CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)

Comment: how to enable csv in ubuntu bash? `apt install bash-builtins` then `enable -f /usr/lib/bash/csv csv` --- thanks @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub

Comment: @Summer-Sky, if `/usr/lib/bash/` is where the loadable builtins are then that should be fine. look at @F.Hauri's post from the  links posted, but in version `5.2` there is a compile option where to put it.

Answer (score 2):

## `readarray` (`mapfile`) and `read -a` disambiguation

### `readarray` == `mapfile` first:

> ```
> help readarray
> readarray: readarray [-d delim] [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]
>     Read lines from a file into an array variable.
>     
>     A synonym for `mapfile'.
> ```

Then

> ```
> help mapfile
> mapfile: mapfile [-d delim] [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]
>     Read lines from the standard input into an indexed array variable.
>     
>     Read lines from the standard input into the indexed array variable ARRAY, or
>     from file descriptor FD if the -u option is supplied.  The variable MAPFILE
>     is the default ARRAY.
>     
>     Options:
>       -d delim    Use DELIM to terminate lines, instead of newline
>       -n count    Copy at most COUNT lines.  If COUNT is 0, all lines are copied
>       -O origin   Begin assigning to ARRAY at index ORIGIN.  The default index is 0
>       -s count    Discard the first COUNT lines read
>       -t  Remove a trailing DELIM from each line read (default newline)
>       -u fd       Read lines from file descriptor FD instead of the standard input
>       -C callback Evaluate CALLBACK each time QUANTUM lines are read
>       -c quantum  Specify the number of lines read between each call to
>                           CALLBACK
> ...
> ```

#### While `read -a`:

> ```
> help read
> read: read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
>     Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.
>     
>     Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
>     if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
>     splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
>     word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
>     the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
>     delimiters.
> ...
>     Options:
>       -a array    assign the words read to sequential indices of the array
>                   variable ARRAY, starting at zero
> ...
> ```

Note:

> Only the characters found in `$IFS` are recognized as word delimiters.
> Useful with `-a` flag!

### Create an array from a splitted string

For creating an array by splitting a string you could either:

```bash
IFS=, read -ra myArray <<<'A,1,spaced string,42'
declare -p myArray
```

```
declare -a myArray=([0]="A" [1]="1" [2]="spaced string" [3]="42")
```

Oe use `mapfile`, but as this command is intented to work of whole *files*, syntax is something counter-intuitive:

```bash
mapfile -td, myArray < <(printf %s 'A,1,spaced string,42')
declare -p myArray
```

```
declare -a myArray=([0]="A" [1]="1" [2]="spaced string" [3]="42")
```

Or, if you want to avoid fork ( *`< <(printf...`* ), you have to

```bash
mapfile -td, myArray <<<'A,1,spaced string,42'
myArray[-1]=${myArray[-1]%$'\n'}
declare -p myArray
```

```
declare -a myArray=([0]="A" [1]="1" [2]="spaced string" [3]="42")
```

This will be a little quicker, but not more readable...

### For you sample:

```bash
mapfile -t rows <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in   
HEREDOC
for row in ${rows[@]};do
    IFS=, read -a cols <<<"$row"
    declare -p cols
done
```

```
declare -a cols=([0]="1" [1]="a" [2]="info")
declare -a cols=([0]="2" [1]="b" [2]="inf")
declare -a cols=([0]="3" [1]="c" [2]="in")
```

```bash
for row in ${rows[@]};do
    IFS=, read -a cols <<<"$row"
    printf ' %s | %s\n' "${cols[0]}" "${cols[2]}"
done
```

```
 1 | info
 2 | inf
 3 | in
```

Or even, if really you want to use `readarray`:

```bash
for row in ${rows[@]};do
    readarray -dt, cols <<<"$row"
    cols[-1]=${cols[-1]%$'\n'}
    declare -p cols
done
```

```
declare -a cols=([0]="1,a,info")
declare -a cols=([0]="2,b,inf")
declare -a cols=([0]="3,c,in")
```

### Playing with *`callback`* option:

(Added some spaces on last line)

```bash
testfunc() { 
    local IFS array cnt line
    read cnt line <<< "$@"
    IFS=,
    read -a array <<< "$line"
    printf ' [%3d]: %3s | %3s :: %s\n' $cnt "${array[@]}"
}
mapfile -t -C testfunc -c 1  <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c d,in fo   
HEREDOC
```

```
 [  0]:   1 |   a :: info
 [  1]:   2 |   b :: inf
 [  2]:   3 | c d :: in fo
```

#### Same, with `-u` flag:

Open the *file descriptor*:

```bash
exec {mydoc}<<HEREDOC
1,a,info                             
2,b,inf                                                                                        
3,c d,in fo   
HEREDOC
```

Then

```bash
mapfile -u $mydoc -C testfunc -c 1
```

```
 [  0]:   1 |   a :: info
 [  1]:   2 |   b :: inf
 [  2]:   3 | c d :: in fo
```

And finally close the *file descriptor*:

```bash
exec {mydoc}<&-
```

### About bash `csv` module,

For further informations about `enable -f /path/to/csv csv`, RFCs and limitations, have a look at [my previous post about **How to parse a CSV file in Bash?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)

Comment: also a great result, but can you move the important part at the top? the code after "For you sample:" ... the rest is a great resource. then i thumbs up too ;)

Comment: Have a look how I use `readarray -td, myArray ` and `myArray[-1]=${myArray[-1]%$'\n'}` for avoiding fork `<(prinf...)` (You begin your answer by *The solution is...*, in wich I doesn't agree. ;)

Comment: i don't agree in first populating an array with the whole file and then iterating through it. also I don't get why proving that readarray is synonymous to mapfile when the question already implies this.  also starting out with the docs is not the order someone expects answers. first the answer, then additional explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `readarray -t -d, arr < <(printf "%s," "$r")`

The special part is [`< <(...)`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/readarray-or-pipe-issue#comment226347_136216) because [readarray](https://helpmanual.io/builtin/readarray/) .... 
there is no proper reason to be found why it first needs a redirection arrow and then process-substitution.  
 Neither in [tldp process-sub](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) nor [SS64](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html) .

 My final understanding is that, `<(...)` opens a named pipe and readarray is waiting for it to close. By moving this in place of a file behind `<`  it is handled by bash as a file input and (anonymously) piped into stdin.

---

example:

```
while read r ; do 
   echo "$r";
   readarray -t -d, arr < <(printf "%s," "$r");
   echo "${arr[0]}";
done <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in   
HEREDOC
```

---

Anyway this is just a reminder for myself, because i keep forgetting and readarray is the only place where i actually need this.

The question was also answered [mostly here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/readarray-or-pipe-issue), [here why the pipe isn't working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9994/130072) and somewhat [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263883/bash-pipe-find-output-into-readarray), but they are difficult to find and the reasoning to comprehend.

for example the `shopt -s lastpipe` solution is not clear at first, but it turns out that in bash all piped elements are usually not executed in the main shell, thus state changes have no effect on the full program. this command changes the behavior to have the last pipe element execute in main (except in an interactive shell)

```
shopt -s lastpipe;
while read r ; do 
    echo "$r";       
    printf "%s," "$r"  | readarray -t -d, arr;
    echo "${arr[0]}"; 
    done <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in   
HEREDOC
```

one alternative to lastpipe would be to do all activity in the sub shell:

```
while read r ; do 
       echo "$r";
       printf "%s," "$r"  | { 
            readarray -t -d, arr ; 
            echo "${arr[0]}"; 
       }
    done <<HEREDOC
1,a,info
2,b,inf
3,c,in   
HEREDOC
```

Comment: `while read r ; do` needs to be `while IFS= read -r r ; do` unless you have a specific need to translate escape sequences and strip leading/trailing blanks from the input.

Comment: Note that lastpipe doesn't work in shells with job control enabled, so relying on it is perilous.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you provide more context?  Do you mean `set +m` ? i did refer to the interactive shell which is explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/readarray-or-pipe-issue

Comment: @EdMorton thank you. my documentation (bash 5.1.16(1) man page) does not say anything about leading/trailing blanks with `-r`  ... but yes I did not care about backslash escape sequences in the content. but great point!

Comment: The `-r` is to stop escape sequences from being interpreted, it's the `IFS=<null>` that stops leading/training spaces from being stripped. Similar to always quoting your variables by default, you need to always use both of those by default (e.g. when you "did not care about backslash escape sequences"), removing either or both only if/when necessary.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the heads up. will keep that in mind

Comment: @EdMorton is my mentioned interpretation correct? 
> "My final understanding is that, <(...) opens a named pipe and readarray is waiting for it to close. By moving this in place of a file behind <  it is handled by bash as a file input and (anonymously) piped into stdin."

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: BTW, stay clear of TLDP -- their bash documentation has a lot of outright incorrect information. The [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) were written _explicitly_ to have a less outdated/wrong/bad-practice-demonstrating reference available, after denizens of the #bash IRC channel got tired of answering questions about problems caused by people copying examples they'd seen in the ABS; the [bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) is also pretty good.