# Iterating over a csv file in bash

Tags: bash

I was under the impression that `read -r` goes through each line, but it's just not working and I havent a clue why it's only doing the first line

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r a b c; do
        d=$(echo "$c"|cut -d' ' -f1)
        for node in $(seq -f "somehost%02.0f" 01 29); do ssh -i ~/file.key  user@$node "zgrep $a /path/*$(date -d $d +'%Y-%m-%d')*"; done >> tmp
done < New.csv
```

CSV file

```
0000007415597221,Authorized,11-SEP-23 10.40.27.000000 AM
0000007415596310,Authorized,11-SEP-23 10.40.30.000000 AM
0000007415596319,Authorized,11-SEP-23 10.40.31.000000 AM
0000007438025843,Authorized,17-SEP-23 05.56.34.000000 PM
0000007442152893,Authorized,18-SEP-23 07.36.24.000000 PM
0000007442154377,Authorized,18-SEP-23 07.36.34.000000 PM
```

The only thing I thought might work was to remove the `>>` and put it while I run the script but to no avail :( any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The problem is with using `ssh` in the loop, it's reading the rest of the file. See the linked question.

Comment: well that answers that :(

Comment: See [BashFAQ/089 (I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) and the [How to keep other commands from "eating" the input](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#How_to_keep_other_commands_from_.22eating.22_the_input) section of [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: All I needed was `-n` in the ssh command and its working - next task is to figure out how to make it run through 250k entries overnight

Comment: See [How to parse a CSV file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)