# Need to write a bash script to do my task. I have several problems when executing the script

Tags: bash, csv, awk, scripting, devops

Company ABC has uncontrolled process of employee’s accounts creation. Currently process means
adding names, email and other personal data manually to the accounts.csv file without any rules.
Department head has decided to improve it based on the naming convention implementation. Good
idea for newcomers, but what to do with current user’s list? You have been asked to help. Could you please
develop automated way (bash script) and create new accounts_new.csv file based on current
accounts.csv and below.

Need to update column name. Name format: first letter of name/surname uppercase and all other letters lowercase.

Need to update column email with domain @abc. Email format: first letter from name and full surname, lowercase. Equals emails should contain location_id.

Sripts should has name task1.sh Path to accounts.csv file should be as argument to the script.

Definition of done. Developed bash script which automatically creates accounts_new.csv and updates columns name and email based on the rules above.

The script below works but there are some mistakes want to solve.

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="accounts.csv"
output_file="accounts_new.csv"

if [ -f "$output_file" ]; then
    rm "$output_file"
fi

head -n 1 "$input_file" > "$output_file"

tail -n +2 "$input_file" | while IFS=',' read -r id location_id name title email department; do
    first_name=$(echo "$name" | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
    surname=$(echo "$name" | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')

    formatted_first_name=$(echo "$first_name" | awk '{print toupper(substr($1,1,1)) tolower(substr($1,2))}')
    formatted_surname=$(echo "$surname" | awk '{print toupper(substr($1,1,1)) tolower(substr($1,2))}')
    formatted_name="$formatted_first_name $formatted_surname"

    formatted_email=$(echo "${formatted_first_name:0:1}${formatted_surname}@abc" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

    echo "$id,$location_id,$formatted_name,$title,$formatted_email,$department" >> "$output_file"
done

echo "New file created: $output_file"

if diff -w -B <(sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' "$input_file") <(sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' "$output_file") >/dev/null; then
    echo "The generated file matches the original file."
else
    echo "There are differences between the generated file and the original file."
fi
```

Comment: Maybe could this help you: [How to parse a CSV file in Bas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: You forgot to include small set of sample input, required output from that same input AND most importantly, the current output **with the errors** (you mentioned in the Title), If you repost, be sure to include that information. Good luck.

Comment: *`there are some mistakes want to solve`* -- and what exactly are the mistakes? without actual sample data, without details of the actual 'mistakes', you're asking us to *guess* at what may be wrong with the script, and there's no guarantee that our *guesses* will actually solve your problem; the description reads like a homework (or lab) assignment in which case I'm guessing you were also provided sample inputs and perhaps the sample output ... providing those data sets would be helpful