Use particular values of each row of csv for command path argument
Not sure why I can't find this answer anywhere.
Input CSV:
201800001779830000,"17798320181.pdf",,,159.0,5371.0,,,,,,2019,"{}",2022-08-25 12:58:20.928,2022-08-26 03:13:35.292,airflow,false,"2018-13-FILE-0000177983"
201800002481440000,"24814420181.pdf",,,180.0,7085.0,,,,,,2018,"{}",2022-08-25 12:57:08.403,2022-08-26 03:13:35.292,airflow,false,"2018-13-FILE-0000248144"
...

Want to run each row as a separate command with with certain columns as input to path values resulting the following commands
aws s3 cp s3://bucket1/prefix1/2019/17798320181.pdf s3://bucket1/prefix2/2019/17798320181.pdf
aws s3 cp s3://bucket1/prefix1/2018/24814420181.pdf s3://bucket1/prefix2/2018/24814420181.pdf
...

So I'd like to use columns 2 and 12 and awk et al to generate these aws commands that will run in succession. Each row should run the command not print it out.  Thanks!
EDIT: If this can be done as a one-liner (using awk, sed etc whatever) would be preferred.

What problem are you having? Loop through the lines of the file, splitting it on comma characters. Then pass columns 2 and 12 as arguments to the command. You'll need to remove the " characters from column 2.

The basic structure is: while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 ...; do ...; done < filename.csv

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286469/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-in-bash for more detailed answers about how to read a CSV in bash.

Sorry I'm not a bash expert. What may be easy to you isn't obvious to me. Can you propose an answer and I can try and edit it? Is it possible to do this as a one-liner?

Sorry I edited the wrong line; fixed.

You're expected to learn the basics elsewhere, this isn't a tutoring service.

Well I think I knew the basics, this may be basic for you, but for most it's not.

You should at least make an attempt to solve it. Then we can see where you're confused and help clear it up.

I did make that attempt. I used awk, and xargs, then realized that xargs was more for args not inline path variable, it didn't occur to me to use a for loop, and given Diego's great answer I see I didn't need to, I believe my mistake was trying to pipe this to xargs. I googled for probably 30 minutes at least.  I apologize for not putting my attempt in the question. I'll make sure to do that next time.

I meant you should post your attempt. We can't help you fix it if you don't show what you tried.

Yes and as I've said, I apologize for not posting it. My mistake.

If you want columns 2 and 12 to be taken as the filenames
awk -F, '{print "s3://bucket1/prefix1/2019/" $2 " s3://bucket1/prefix2/2019/" $12}' FILE | xargs -tL1 aws s3 cp


Thanks so much Diego for the helpful answer.  You may misunderstood my question because I made the wrong edit (which I've since fixed).  I've made edits to your answer and requested review.  awk -F, '{print "s3://bucket1/prefix1/"$12"/" $2 " s3://bucket1/prefix2/"$12"/" $2}' tribal_a133_documents.csv | xargs -tL1 aws s3 cp is what I was looking for but your great answer (without even using a for-loop which I thought was possible--nice!) helped me find this solution. Thanks again!

Thanks again for being smart enough to be able to answer with a very useful answer and not being like so many of the diks that have ruined this place.
